# ¿Cómo descargar la clave pública en AWS?

Tags: aws

Un compañero de trabajo me pidió que compartiera con él las claves públicas PGP mias para
para enviarnos credenciales encriptadas para acceder a los datos. Pero no sé como hacer eso.
No fui yo quien creó mi clave, fue el antiguo colega quien me envió un archivo csv con mis identificadores:

```
User name,Password,Access key ID,Secret access key,Console login link
elmio@email.com,unpassword, ELACCESSKEYID, S3/CR33T//AcCessKeY , https://numeros.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
```

Entonces sigue el [la documentacion para descargar la clave publica](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/download-public-key.html) pero no hay ninguna claves:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utiliso Windows10

Answer (score 0):

Consultas:

- A donde estas tratando de ingresar(consola, auna maquina virtual,
  etc.)?
- Que necesitas hacer?
- Quieres utilizar el SDK?
- Otro?

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Las claves no se pueden descargar de AWS. Es una medida de seguridad. Tu eres el responsable de mantener a buen recaudo las claves que uses en AWS.

Si, por ejemplo, creas un nuevo par de claves SSH desde AWS, en ese preciso momento se te permite descargar la clave, pero nunca más se te permitirá volver a hacerlo.

Este mecanismo evita que alguien se descargue las claves, lo que le permitiría acceder sin restricciones a las diferentes máquinas, servicios y datos.

Para almacenar claves que se puedan recuperar, existe el servicio *Secrets Manager*. En ese servicio puedes guardar claves o datos y recuperarlos desde cualquier máquina o servicio siempre y cuando tenga acceso a dichos datos.